# Clarification of a bitwise statement

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

What does the following condition if(a & (a-1)/2) mean in C?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int a;
   scanf("%d", &a);

   if(a & (a-1)/2)
   {
      printf("Yes\n");
   }
   else{
       printf("No\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I didn't get the meaning of / operator here. what does the division operator mean in the condition ?

Comment: It divides the result of the expression `a-1` by 2.

Comment: looks like it's trying to tell if a is odd or even

Comment: @Mawg `(a & 1)` will be sufficient for that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The division operator `/` simply divides the left hand side by the right hand side. In this case the right hand side is 2, so it's shifting `a-1` right by one bit (an arithmetic shift, which sign-extends the integer).

The whole expression therefore calculates - for `a>=0` - whether `a` and `((a-1)>>1)` both have any of the same bits set (in which case `&` will produce a non-zero value). For `a<0` see the comment at the end.

Here's some test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
      printf ("%3d %s\n", i, (i & (i - 1) / 2) ? "yes" : "no");
    }
  exit (0);
}
```

which gives

```
  0 no
  1 no
  2 no
  3 yes
  4 no
  5 no
  6 yes
  7 yes
  8 no
  9 no
 10 no
 11 yes
 12 yes
 13 yes
 14 yes
 15 yes
 16 no
 17 no
 18 no
 19 yes
 20 no
 21 no
 22 yes
 23 yes
 24 yes
 25 yes
 26 yes
 27 yes
 28 yes
 29 yes
 30 yes
 31 yes
 32 no
 33 no
 34 no
 ... abbreviated for clarity ...
```

This detects numbers that either:

- have two or more adjacent binary 1s or;
- are negative, but not `MININT`.

Here's how:

- If `a>=0`, then `(a-1)/2` == `a/2` (as rounding is always towards zero). So this is equivalent (for `a>=0`) to `a & (a>>1)` which will be one if the bit to the right of any bit in `a` is set, i.e. if there are two or more adjacent ones.
- If `a<0` and `a!=MININT`, (and thus have `1` as its MSB), then `(a-1)` must also be negative and less than `-1`, so `(a-1)/2` must also be negative (and thus have `1` as its MSB), in which case `a & ((a-1)/2))` is non-zero because its MSB must also be 1.
- If `a==MININT`, then `a-1` is `MAXINT`, so (a-1)/2 has no bits that are both 1.

Comment: The equivalence to "shift right by 1 bit" is not true for negative values.

Comment: It shifts right by 1 bit except the sign bit which remains unchanged.

Comment: @AndreyT yes it is. It's an arithmetic shift right (or exactly what the `>>` operator does with an `int`), which sign-extends.

Comment: @abligh: In C, right-shifting a signed negative integer is implementation-defined.

Comment: @rici - fair point. But it's still equal to an arithmetic shift right.

Comment: @abligh: On some systems. On other architectures, it's equal to a logical shift right. (Or it could even be something else entirely)

Comment: @rici no. `/2` is *always* equal to an arithmetic shift right (i.e. sign extended). It never logical shifts right. I agree that on some systems `>>` may do an arithmetic shift right, or take your inside leg measurement, or whatever as it's undefined behaviour.

Comment: @abligh: That is false. Signed division by 2 is NOT equivalent to a shift, any shift. It is not equivalent to an arithmetic (sigh preserving) shift. In C (and C++) language signed division is required to round toward zero. This kills shift equivalence immediately. For example, `-5 / 2` is required to produce `-2`, while `-5 >> 1` is `-3` in case of arithmetic shift. Note that there's no equivalence even on 2's complement architecture.

Comment: The closes you get to a shift-based implementation is to perform an arithmetic shift and then add 1 for negative divisors. That need to "add 1" is what makes it non-equivalent.

Comment: Also, incorrect on "undefined in C". Right-shifting negative values is implementation-defined in C. The same is true in C++. And to detect two adjacent 1s one just has to do `a & (a>>1)`. It still does not explain where that `(a - 1)` came from and why it is there.

Comment: In fact, on exotic *signed-magnitude* or *1's-complement* architectures the proper C-style division by 2 can be implemented by a sign-preserving shift even for negative values. But on on our everyday *2's-complement* architecture arithmetic shift does not implement the proper division by 2, as required by C and C++ languages.

Comment: @a_guest: Yes, normally this is what it does. But on 2's-complement machines such shift does not implement "division by 2" as required by C and C++. Which is why it is irrelevant here.

Comment: @AndreyT: Quite right. I was just about to correct my comment. (By the way, +1 for "sigh preserving".)

Comment: @AndreyT apologies - I missed the rounding point. You are right about that of course.

Comment: If we pretend that `a` is unsigned, then `((a & (a - 1) >> 1) != 0) == ((a & (a >> 1)) != 0)` for all `a`. The right hand side makes it clear that it does indeed detect 2 adjacent 1s.

Comment: @harold - I think I have a definitive explanation of what this does.

Answer (score 2):

For non-negative values, division by 2 is equivalent to shifting it 1 bit to the right. For negative values it is not equivalent, but I suspect that the authors of the code did not intend it to work with negative values.

(Note that this non-equivalence has nothing to do with exotic non-2's-complement architectures or arithmetic sifts. In C and C++ language signed division is required to round towards 0, which makes it impossible to implement signed division by a simple shift for negative values on 2's complement architectures. A post-shift correction is required.)

Now, as for what the whole `a & (a - 1) / 2` expression is doing... Let's restrict consideration for non-negative values only.

Subtracting 1 is equivalent to inverting all trailing 0 bits in the number and then inverting the last (least significant) 1 bit. Division by 2 is equivalent to shift right by 1 bit.

In the context of `&` operation, the whole thing is equivalent to: kill the last 1 bit in `a`, shift the whole thing to the right 1 bit and `&` it with the original value.

I don't see the point of killing the last 1 bit in this case. It looks like for positive values the whole thing is equivalent to `a & (a / 2)` (i.e. to `a & (a >> 1))`), which simply detects if there are two adjacent 1 bits in the original `a`.

Comment: Not all versions of C require signed division to round down – C89 permits round-towards-zero (which is ceiling for negative numbers).

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant: Yes, but in formal context an unqualified reference to language's name is assumed to refer to its current version. True, C89/90 allowed implementations to choose Euclidean division over Fortran division, but even C89/90 recommended the latter choice.

Answer (score 0):

It substracts 1 from a then divides it by 2 and after that it makes a bit-and operation.

Answer (score 0):

In the condition `/` operator simply does division. The only thing that matters is whether the result in condition is 0 (false) or not 0 (true).

As fot what the program actually does, it looks binary math related so you should ask someone who knows more about that.

Answer (score -1):

In the expression a & (a - 1) / 2 there is a bitwise and operator, and a division operator. It is highly unusual that these are used together. Therefore, I don't know what the precedence is (does it divide a-1 by two and does a bitwise and with a, or does it do a bitwise and of a and a-1, then divide the result by two). I actually don't care what the precedence is, because I don't know what precedence the programmer writing the code assumed it would be.

If you see code like this, you need to find out what it does, you need to find out what it was intended to do, if both are the same you add parentheses to make the intent clear, and if they are not the same you have found a bug and figure out how it affects the program and what to do about it.

Comment: `/` has higher precedence than `&`.